# License issues with ikvm.net?

Tags: licensing, java, ikvm

I'm thinking about the usage of ikvm.net. While ikvm.net has a license which can be used by commercial applications, openjdk will be developed under GPL.

My question is due to the fact that ikvm.net is delivering an openjdk .net assembly does this effect the application which is going to use ikvm.net?

Comment: Ask a lawyer in your country. It's the *only* way to get an answer you can work with.

Comment: Sure that I'm going to do this. But could be that somebody has experiences with it and can give a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my personal opinion and may be wrong. I am not a lawyer.

The license of the OpenJDK is GPL+[linking exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception) and not simple GPL. This means you can write commercial application that based on OpenJDK. The writing of commercial application is the cause for the linking exception.

IKVM has also not the problems of Android because the license is not more free like a Apache license. The OpenJDK part is continue under the GPL+linking exception.

The larger problems are the patents. The patents for Java can only used if the TCK passed. IKVM does not pass the TCK. I think never has test it.

But the most patents are invalid. Thanks to Google. The most patents are more related to the VM self and not to the API. Things like Garbage Collection and Reflection are not part or IKVM. This are features of the .NET Framework.

In some weeks we will know more. If Android has no patents problems then IKVM has also no patents problems.